# Problems to access/change private variables in an operator overload of a different class

Tags: c++

I have a problems with the following initial situation:
I have 2 classes. For example a class A and class B. In these two classes I have a private variable var. I have created two objects of the two classes in the main (e.g. obj1 and obj2). Next I would like to make a statement of the form obj1 = obj2. To do this, I want to make an operator overload in this operator overload, I want to do a calculation with var, e.g.

```
/*
--------------------------------------------------------
Header
--------------------------------------------------------
*/

#ifndef A_h
#define A_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
Definition of class A
*/
class B;
class A{
    double var;

public:
    A (double inputVar);
    A();
    A operator = (const B &rs);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const A & obj);
};

/*
Definition of class B
*/
class B{
    double var;
    
public:
    B (double inputVar);
    B();
    B operator = (const A &rs);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const B & obj);
};
#endif /* A_h */
```

```
/*
--------------------------------------------------------
class A
--------------------------------------------------------
*/
#include "A.h"

A::A(double inputVar):var(inputVar){
}

A::A(){}

A A::operator = (const B &rs){
    A test=0; //implemented to make it runnable
     this->var = rs.var * 2; // I want to do something like this
    return test;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A & obj){
    os<<obj.var;
    return os;
}
```

```
/*
--------------------------------------------------------
class B
--------------------------------------------------------
*/

#include "A.h"

B::B(double inputVar):var(inputVar){
}

B::B(){}

B B::operator = ( const A &rs){
    B stat=0; 
    return stat;//implemented to make it runnable
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const B & obj){
    os<<obj.var;
    return os;
}
```

```
/*
--------------------------------------------------------
main
--------------------------------------------------------
*/
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   A objA1;
   A objA2 (20.4);
   A objA3=25;

   B objB1;
   B objB2(20.4);

   //objA2=objB2;
   //objA1 = objA2 = objA3 = 50.5;
    
    cout << objA2 << endl; // Ausgabe: c1 = 12.3C
    cout << objB2 << endl; // Ausgabe: f1 = 10.5F*/
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now I have the problem that I cannot access the variable var because it is private. Class A and B should not be mutual friends. I can't find an approach how I can solve the problem (Maybe over the reference ??).

EDIT:

I get the following error message

```
Use of overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous (with operand types 'A' and 'double')
```

I am thankful for every hint.

Comment: what...? might be more clear to add definition of your classes. Can't you use setter/getters. Also why is an object A being assigned instance of B * 2, seems odd.

Comment: `operator =` should change the contents of `this`

Comment: `operator=` should modify the left hand side of the assignment and return `*this` as `A&` , not return a new object. But it's not clear what you are asking, can you show a [mre] please?

Comment: Sorry for the cryptic definition of my problem. Hopefully with my edit the problem is understandable.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Yes, but I need to do a calculation  to convert between two units. I thought it wasn't helpful to add the whole calculation therefore I simplified it. Sorry if it caused any confusion.

Comment: @churill Thank you for the link. I think now should it be reproducible. I only leaved out the constructors.

Comment: What is `rs * 2`? Do you mean `rs.val * 2`?

Comment: @cigien Yes, but because it doesn't work I thought it might be better to leave it out. Sorry for the confusion I edited it.

Comment: There are a bunch of errors in your code. Please paste the error messages into the question.

Comment: @cigien The only error message I get is that var is a private member of class B. But I will make a running duplicate. Should have done it in the first place sorry.

Comment: @cigien Ok, I edited my code. Obviously it is ambiguous but the message should go away if I am able to access the private member of B

Comment: To access the member, just add a getter to `B`. That won't solve the ambiguity problem though. You could fix that by making one of the constructors `explicit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access a class private data member (`var` in this case) you should add a `get()` function, as @Omid CompSCI first stated in his comment.
A MWE (I preserved your assignment operators that double the given input):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B;

/*
Definition of class A
*/
class A{
    double var;

public:
    A (double inputVar): var(inputVar) {}
    A(): var(0) {}
    A& operator = (const A &);
    A& operator = (const B &);   // new, converts B->A
    A& operator = (double);      // new
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const A &);

    double get() const {return var;}
};

/*
Definition of class B
*/
class B{
    double var;

public:
    B (double inputVar): var(inputVar) {}
    B(): var(0) {}
    B& operator = (const B &);
    B& operator = (const A &);      // new, converts A->B
    B& operator = (double);         // new
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const B &);
    double get() const {return var;}
};

A& A :: operator = (const A & rs) {
    if (this == &rs)
        return *this;       // make sure you aren't self-assigning
    this->var = rs.var * 2;
    return *this;
}
B& B :: operator = (const B & rs) {
    if (this == &rs)
        return *this; 
    this->var = rs.var * 2;
    return *this;
}
A& A :: operator = (const B & rs) {
    this->var = rs.get() * 2;
    return *this;
}
B& B :: operator = (const A & rs) {
    this->var = rs.get() * 2;
    return *this;
}
A& A :: operator = (double rs) {
    this->var = rs * 2;
    return *this;
}
B& B:: operator = (double rs) {
    this->var = rs * 2;
    return *this;
}

/*
main
*/
int main()
{
    A objA1;
    A objA2 (20.4);
    A objA3=25;

    B objB1;
    B objB2(20.4);

    objA3=objB2;
    cout << "objA3 contents, " << objA3.get() 
         << ", are equal to 2*objB2's: " << objB2.get() << endl;

    objA1 = 50.5;
    objA2 = objA1;
    objA3 = objA2;
    cout << "Now objA1: " << objA1.get() 
         << ", objA2: " << objA2.get() << ", and objA3: " << objA3.get() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment I will add the getter to my code. This is really helpful :-) Unfortunately I have to keep the syntax of the main function. So I can't use getter for the output and my assignments have to be like ```objA1 = objA2 = objA3 = 50.5;```

Comment: @marcy_del: yes I see you have drastically changed the code-bit in your question, I submitted my answer before that. I think you can use the custom `operator<< ` you set up in `A` and `B` for your output.
The copy constructors I introduced however need the `get()`functions.
I am not sure you can have something like `objA1 = objA2 = objA3 = 50.5;` in C++ though...

Comment: ...meaning an assignment statement has only 2 sides, `left = right;` cannot have more assignments than 2 before the `;`

Comment: @marcy_del: please upvote and accept answer if this has helped.
My curiosity, how have you dealt with the multiple, one- line assignment statement?

Comment: I don't know for sure, sorry. But I will add my code here when I am allowed to so you can see it for yourself if you want.

Comment: ok thanks. Although you probably have broken that expression in multiple assignments, I guess

Answer (score 2):

You could also define a template for override the `operator=` function. This enables you to assign A-object to B-object and B-object to A-object.
Removing the const of `rs` in

```
template<typename T>
A operator = (T& rs){...}
```

enables `objA1 = objA2 = objA3 = 50.5;` in main.cpp

Sorry, I was a little bit lazy because I put the code-definition in the header-file.

Header Letter.hpp

```
#ifndef Letter_h
#define Letter_h

class Letter
{
    public:
    double get_var() const
    {
        return var;
    }
    protected:
    double var;
};
#endif /* Letter_h */
```

Header A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_h
#define A_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Letter.hpp"

using namespace std;

/*
Definition of class A
*/

class A : public Letter
{

    public:
    A(double inputVar)
    {
        var=inputVar;
    }
    
    A()=default;
    
    template<typename T>
    A operator = (T& rs) //removing const fixed objA1 = objA2 = objA3 = 50.5; in main.cpp
    {
        this->var = rs.get_var() * 2; // I want to do something like this
        return var;
    }
    
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &strm, const A &a)
    {
        strm<<a.var;
        return strm;
    }
};
#endif /* A_h */
```

Header B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_h
#define B_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Letter.hpp"

using namespace std;

/*
Definition of class B
*/

class B : public Letter 
{

    public:
    B(double inputVar)
    {
        var=inputVar;
    }
    
    B()=default;
    
    template<typename T>
    B operator = (const T &rs)
    {
        return this->var;
    }
    
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &strm, const B &b)
    {
        strm<<b.var;
        return strm;
    }
};
```

The main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   A objA1;
   A objA2 (20.4);
   A objA3=25;
   A objA4=26;

   B objB1;
   B objB2(20.4);
   B objB3=25;

   objA2=objB2;
   
   objB3=objA4;
   
   objA1 = objA2 = objA3 = 50.5;
    
    cout << objA2 << endl;
    cout << objB2 << endl;
    cout << objA3 << endl; 
    cout << objB3 << endl; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After reading the solution of @Lingo, you should prefer his solution. It avoids the template.
Hint: You will need a forward declaration of class A in B.hpp and one of class B in A.hpp.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the Problem :-) In my finished code I only made 1 header file so I only needed one forward declaration.

Comment: @UweJ : you are right, all it takes is removing the `const` from the assignment operator parameter and you can have multiple assignments in one line (it evaluates right to left); it also does away with the need of an extra operator when assigning a `double`...+1